# Unexplained space near top of document in FireFox only

Tags: html, css, firefox, web

I'm having an issue where a margin that is being applied to a div seems to also be getting applied to the document body *in FireFox only*.

Some googling around the internet seems to make reference to collapsing margins, and while that may be the case, I don't think I fully understand what's going on.

I've created an example http://jsfiddle.net/davidwkennedy/3BQrw/ (view in FF, and then any other browser to compare).

```
   <body>
  <form id="form1" action="nothing">
     <div>
        <div>
           <p style="float:left; border:solid 1px red">Why is this text not anchored at the top of the page?</p>
           <div style="clear:both;"> </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div style="margin-top:100px;">
        <p>hello world</p>
     </div>
  </form>
```

Could someone please help me understand what's going on?

Thanks

(edit: it's been a while since I asked this, but I wanted to update with the FireFox version. I don't recall what I was using when I originally wrote this, but this issue is still occurring in 26.0)

Comment: That's why I don't like floats

Comment: It is because of margin collapse, but darned if I know why.  If you start adding borders to the divs, you can see the margins disappear:  http://jsfiddle.net/3BQrw/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is related to collapsing margins. Add `overflow:auto` to your form and you'll see the issue disappear.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3BQrw/2/)**

Comment: That works perfectly, but I still don't understand 
(a) Why FireFox- what's different it's rendering engine that causes this? and (b) While I think I understand the basic concept behind collapsing margins, I don't understand how it would cause this particular issue - and how does removing the float interact with collapsing margins?

Comment: I'm not sure either, and it appears to be the div with the 100px margin that causes it. Remove that (without using the overflow rule) and it also returns to normal. I'll say that it does seem odd, especially how Chrome behaves as expected and FF appears to add extra space where no would seem to need to exist.

Answer (score 1):

That is really strange. It is telling that when you remove the float from the p it works as expected.

For some reason when Firefox computes margin collapse on the body, it adds that margin to the body and not the child element. I would guess that this is a glitch, though I have not double checked the spec.

The part that is surely a glitch is that Firefox is not fully computing the `clear:both` applied to the child div, because if it did the hello world margin collapse would not be applied to body. The outer containing div will automatically be set to `clear:none` when a child p is set to `float`, that is weird but expected. However, when that second child div is set to `clear:both`, something clearly gets screwy. I doubt you will find a logical answer for that part as it is almost certainly a bug in Firefox' rendering.

Long story short, you have probably discovered not one but two bugs in Firefox' rendering.

Answer (score 0):

`*{margin:0; padding:0;}`  for everything and can give style for each or give just for your form "`form {margin:0; padding:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

You might need a CSS Reset. I use this one, coded by Eric Meyer. It's the best shot. Try using this for every site you start building. Here's the CSS code (place it always at the top of the main CSS or as a @import inside the main CSS). This worked for me in your fiddle! Luck!

```
a, abbr, acronym, address ,applet, article, aside, audio, b, blockquote, big, body, center, canvas, caption, cite, code, command, datalist, dd, del, details, dfn, dl, div, dt, em, embed, fieldset, figcaption, figure, font, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, html, i, iframe, img, ins, kbd, keygen, label, legend, li, meter, nav, object, ol, output, p, pre, progress, q, s, samp, section, small, span, source, strike, strong, sub, sup, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, th, tr, tdvideo, tt, u, ul, var {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

ul {list-style: none; }
blockquote, q {quotes: none; }

table, table td {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

img {vertical-align: top; }

embed {vertical-align: top; }

article, aside, audio, canvas, command, datalist, details, embed, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, keygen, meter, nav, output, progress, section, source, video {display: block; }

mark, rp, rt, ruby, summary, time{display: inline; }
```